# C struct type correspondences in Julia

Tags: c, struct, julia

I try to use the C functions in Julia with structs as arguments, I call the functions, but something goes wrong. A simple example is the following:

**In C:**

```
typedef struct {
    int width;
    int height;
    int stride;
    float* elements;
} Matriz;
```

is a simple struct that store a Matrix, with `width`, `heigth`, `stride` and `elements` fields

```
float GetElm(const Matriz A, int row, int col)
{
    return (row < A.height && col < A.width ?
        A.elements[row * A.stride + col] : 0);
}
```

is a function that returns a element of the Matrix given the row and column.

**in Julia:**

```
immutable Matriz
width::Cint
height::Cint
stride::Cint
elements::Array{Float32,1}
end

M=Matriz(5,5,5,Array{Float32,1}(collect(0:24))) #creating a Matrix of 5x5


ccall((:GetElm,"path/to/dll"),Float32,(Matriz,Cint,Cint),M,0,1)
```

the `ccall` should return `1.0` according to the code, but returns another value, is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do a function call with `ccall` directly with an array argument, Julia sends the native address of the `Array`.

With `struct`s, however, the process is not automatic. One way you can still send the native address of the array is using `pointer`. You need to update your `struct` in Julia if you are going to use this method.

```
struct Matriz
    width::Cint
    height::Cint
    stride::Cint
    elements::Ptr{Cfloat}
end

arr = Array{Float32,1}(collect(0:24))
M=Matriz(5,5,5, pointer(arr)) #creating a Matrix of 5x5
ccall((:GetElm,"mylib.so"),Float32,(Matriz,Cint,Cint),M,0,1)
```

Before doing so please read the manual for [`pointer`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/c/#Base.pointer), as it is an unsafe operation due to Julia GC.